# How to get only one value in a variable of parent component, by selecting and switching to any of the option in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

i'm new to React and made a small gaming component which have `indoor` and `outdoor` options. In outdoor Item, we have 2 radio buttons and in indoor Item, we have multiple check boxes. My object is we have to get only one value either for outdoor or indoor games fields (indoor games may have multiple values). But not getting any idea how to get the value from these fields.

for Indoor and Outdoor:

```
   <Form>
            <Form.Field
              as="h4"
              control={Radio}
              label="Foot-Ball"
              key="Foot-Ball"
              value="Foot-Ball"
              checked={this.props.game === "Foot-Ball"}
              onChange={this.props.onChange}
            />
            <Form.Field
              as="h4"
              control={Radio}
              label="Cricket"
              key="Cricket"
              value="Cricket"
              checked={this.props.game === "Cricket"}
              onChange={this.props.onChange}
            />{" "}
          </Form>
```

I'm getting output in this way [image: snippet]

My objective is for the variable `game`, either i should get radio button value or i have to get indoor game values but not both in game variable.

Can anyone help me in this?

Here is the working one: "https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-moon-frub1?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue:** The `game` state gets state from both the indoor and outdoor inputs mixed up, and when you try spreading in the previous state's outdoor game `game` strings, they are interpreted as character arrays since they are iterable. They get spread in a character-at-a-time.

**Expected:** One of the Outdoor Games radio button result value strings **OR** an array of Indoor Games checked value id strings.

**Solution:** Add a second piece of state to track which "tab" you are interacting with, i.e. indoor/outdoor. (*I.E. use the fact the event handler was invoked*)

```
this.state = {
  indoor: null,
  game: ""
};
```

Add toggling `indoor` false upon interaction with the "outdoor" radio buttons.

```
handleRadioSelect = (e, { value }) => {
  this.setState({ indoor: false, game: value });
};
```

Then use a check in the "indoor" checkbox handler to see if *already* interacting with the indoor options *or* if the UI *just switched from* the outdoor side.

```
handleCheck = id => {
  const { game, indoor } = this.state;

  if (!indoor) {
    // switching from outdoor games
    // set indoor and initialize array
    this.setState({ indoor: true, game: [id] });
  } else {
    // filter array as per usual
    const result = game.includes(id)
      ? game.filter(x => x !== id)
      : [...game, id];

    this.setState({ game: result });
  }
};
```

[image: Edit sharp-davinci-qmsbp]

Comment: Can you please help me in new query ? "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833772/unable-to-validate-dropdown-once-we-click-on-the-submit-button-using-reactjs"

Answer (score 0):

In `handleCheck`, your first parameter won't contain information which you are looking for, they will be present in second parameter of callback function. So, you need to use second parameter. Also, you were destructuring `value` from `state` instead of `this.props`.

Updated sandbox with working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-gates-b4jsn

Comment: But i want the value of the `game` variable. For example if i choose `carrom` and `ludo` from the indoor games then the `game` variable should show `game: "carrom and ludo"`. if i choose outdoor game without choosing indoor game then the "game" variable should show `game: "cricket"`

Comment: I don't have access to my laptop till tomorrow morning... Will provide a solution for this one tomorrow morning

Comment: Oh... No problem... I'll wait