# How to store value in one variable outside the component using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have went through this link "[How to get only one value by selecting and switching to any of the option using reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632723/how-to-get-only-one-value-by-selecting-and-switching-to-any-of-the-option-using)". I have similar component where i want to store either radio button value or Checkbox values in one variable which is in the App component. But i didn't find any solution to it. Can anyone help me in this? So that it would be useful for me and for the person who posted.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. May I suggest you review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please share your attempt and specifically what the issue is.

Comment: @DrewReese - Hi, I have 2 components - one is child component - which have radio buttons and checkbox buttons, if we click on radio button or checkbox button then the value needs to get stored in App component variable (Parent component).

Comment: It's generally acceptable to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code, without it help is not likely to arrive. What you describe seems to be a fairly simple scenario. What have you tried?

Comment: @DrewReese - I apologize, But i've provided the link above in my query, where the similar question have been asked. So inorder to not to make any duplication of the query. I did not put similar coding

Answer (score 0):

In App component:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({
    radioValue: '',
    checkBoxValue: '',
});
const handleChangeInput = e => {
    setValue({
        ...value,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
};
```

In Child component:

```
<input
     type="radio"
     name="radioValue"
     value={value}
     onChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
/>
```